# Нанооптимизация в цикле for

Tags: c#, clr

Например, есть массив с элементами.

```
int [] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

1. Открыв ILSpy, обнаружил что (++i)преинкремент стал постинкриментом(i++), хотя казалось бы, должно быть наоборот.
2. number.Length высчитывается 1 раз или при каждой итерации??(по идее каждый раз, но мало ли среда как-то это оптимизирует)
   Есть ли смысл выносить условие в отдельную переменную перед циклом?

Comment: Зачем эта экономия на спичках?

Comment: Я для этого и спрашиваю, есть ли в этом какой-либо смысл, например во втором случае, делать еще 1 переменную, в ущерб читаемости кода или нет

Comment: @TorSen не стоит. JIT сам справится с таким

Comment: Хорошо. А что с первым пунктом?

И где собственно про этом можно почитать, дабы не заниматься непонятно чем.

Comment: Микрооптимизация уже не в моде, теперь популярна нанооптимизация. )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Вы смотрите не туда.

Реальной оптимизацией занимается JIT-компилятор, а он довольно умный. Для вашего кода, он произвёл следующий объектный код (разумеется, Release-режим и без отладчика):

```
00007FF88B8B04ED  xor         edi,edi  ; i = 0
00007FF88B8B04EF  movsxd      rcx,edi  
00007FF88B8B04F2  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rsi+rcx*4+10h]  ; ecx = numbers[i]
00007FF88B8B04F6  call        00007FF8E9C19E40  ; Console.WriteLine
00007FF88B8B04FB  inc         edi               ; i++
00007FF88B8B04FD  cmp         edi,5             ; if (i < 5)
00007FF88B8B0500  jl          00007FF88B8B04EF  ; repeat
```

Вы видите, что не только исчезла разница между пре- и пост-инкрементом, не только исчезло повторное чтение `Length`, а ещё оптимизатор смог понять, что длина равна константе 5.

Поверьте, компиляторы справляются с нанооптимизациями куда лучше нас с вами.

---

На уровне IL-кода разницы между пре- и постинкрементом нет*:

```
IL_001e: ldloc.1
IL_001f: ldc.i4.1
IL_0020: add
IL_0021: stloc.1
```

То, что ILSpy декомпилировал эту последовательность команд на C# как постинкремент, это исключительно для удобства читателей (постинкремент привычнее).

---

Ну и финальный совет: нет никаких письменных правил (кроме личного опыта) по поводу того, что быстро, а что медленно. Хуже того, любые «правила» с выходом новой версии компилятора станут скорее всего неправильными: оптимизаторы улучшаются каждый день. Поэтому:

- старайтесь писать так, чтобы ваш код был *читаем*, не увлекайтесь нанооптимизациями,
- профилируйте ваш код регулярно и устраняйте bottleneck'и.

---

*Как правильно подсказывает в комментариях @PetSerAl, разница между пре- и постинкрементом в C# (в отличие от C++) состоит лишь в том, какое значение возвращается выражением. Поэтому для случая, когда результатом инкремента никто не пользуется, их смысл всегда одинаков (для любого типа, не только для `int`).

Comment: *На уровне IL-кода (для `int`!) разницы между пре- и постинкрементом нет* IMHO, дело тут не в `int`, а в том, что результат не используется.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Кстати, да, для C# разницы между пре- и постинкрементом просто нет. Это я с C++ перепутал, там разница возможна. Спасибо за уточнение!

Comment: В С++:
Преинкримент  - увеличение объекта на единицу.
Постинкримент - создается копия объекта, оригинал увеличивается на единицу, и возвращается копия?

А в C# я так понимаю такого нет?

Comment: @TorSen В C# всегда возвращается копия. Преинкремент семантически выглядит так: `var r = op_Increment(x); x = r; return r;`, а постинкремент: `var r = x; x = op_Increment(r); return r;`. Если ли же возвращать ничего не нужно, то обе операции вырождаются в `x = op_Increment(x);`.